# Determining why it is true that $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} f(x) f(y) dy dx = (\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx)^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The following statement is a true/false question:

If $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ then $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} f(x) f(y) dy dx = (\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx)^2$

This answer is apparently true and the solution given is:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} f(x) f(y) dy dx  = \int_{0}^{1} \Big(\int_{0}^{1} f(x) f(y) dx\Big) dy$$

Here, $f(y)$ is a constant because we are integrating with respect to $x$ so we can pull it out.

So we have

$$\int_{0}^{1} \Big[f(y) \Big(\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx\Big) \Big] dy$$

Now we are integrating with respect to $y$ so $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx$ is a constant and we can pull it out.

Now have $$\Big(\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx\Big) \int_{0}^{1} f(y) dy$$

$$=\Big(\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx\Big)^2$$

Because $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{1} f(y) dy $

It's this last statement that I don't understand. Namely, why/how do I know that $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{1} f(y) dy$? I understand the other steps.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are just placeholders.  They don't hold any real meaning except inside the integral.  Using a different label for the same placeholder doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Integration variable is so called bound, dummy variable and integral is know as variable binding operator : such variable can be
replaced with any other symbol, unequal with used ones,  without changing the meaning.

Comment: but what if I chose functions so that $f(x)\neq f(y)$. Im just not sure why this statement is always true, and im not totally sure what you mean by placeholder

Comment: @user477465 Both integrals literally mean the same thing, namely the integral of $f$ over $[0,1]$. They are just different notation. It's the same reason why $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(y) = y^2$ define the same function.

Comment: 1. If you're not convinced that the integrals mean the same thing, just use the substitution $y=x$ to apply "integration by substitution" on the first integral. 2. If I say that $P(x)$ is true for each $x,$ then that's the same as saying that $P(y)$ is true for each $y,$ isn't it?